# data.map not displaying content in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a list with MUI, I'm getting the list in console.log but nothing is shown no errors no data only the console.log.

This is a sample of the data I receive:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "navn": "Til rådighed",
        "beloeb": 20000,
        "tilhors_id": null,
        "title": 0,
        "subtotal": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "navn": "før bryllup",
        "beloeb": 0,
        "tilhors_id": null,
        "title": 1,
        "subtotal": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "navn": "Invitationer",
        "beloeb": 0,
        "tilhors_id": 1,
        "title": 0,
        "subtotal": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "navn": "Subtotal før bryllup",
        "beloeb": 0,
        "tilhors_id": 1,
        "title": 0,
        "subtotal": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "navn": "til bryllup",
        "beloeb": 0,
        "tilhors_id": null,
        "title": 1,
           "subtotal": 0
        }
    ]
```

and here is my `map` function:

```
    const listItems = (id) => {
        console.log(liste)
        if (liste === []) {
            getList()
        } else {
        liste.map((l) => {
            if (id === l.tilhors_id) {
                console.log(l)
                return (
                    <List
                        sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 500, bgcolor: 'white' }}
                        component="nav"
                        aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
                        subheader={
                            <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
                                {l.navn}
                            </ListSubheader>
                        }
                        key={l.id}
                    >
                        <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
                            <ListItemText primary={l.navn} />
                            {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                        </ListItemButton>
                        {!l.subtotal ? (
                            <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                                <List component="div" disablePadding>
                                    <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} onClick={handleClick}>
                                        <div>{l.navn} {l.beloeb}</div>
                                        <ListItemText primary="Starred" />
                                        <Button>X</Button>
                                    </ListItemButton>
                                </List>
                            </Collapse>) :
                            (<ListItemButton>
                                <ListItemText primary={l.navn} />
                            </ListItemButton>)}
                    </List>
                )
            }
        })
     }
    }
```

I tried putting it in Codesandbox without the map and it showed it as it was meant to, I'm lost here because I don't get any error just a blank page...

Comment: it doesnt work because the thilhors_id doesn't match your id argument which you pass to your list, "tilhors_id=null

Comment: I think you forgot to return the mapped jsx from the function listItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` with a condition is not ideal in most cases. If we don't handle it with all proper returns, the list will return with some `undefined` values. You can check below implementation

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "navn": "Til rådighed",
        "beloeb": 20000,
        "tilhors_id": null,
        "title": 0,
        "subtotal": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "navn": "før bryllup",
        "beloeb": 0,
        "tilhors_id": null,
        "title": 1,
        "subtotal": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "navn": "Invitationer",
        "beloeb": 0,
        "tilhors_id": 1,
        "title": 0,
        "subtotal": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "navn": "Subtotal før bryllup",
        "beloeb": 0,
        "tilhors_id": 1,
        "title": 0,
        "subtotal": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "navn": "til bryllup",
        "beloeb": 0,
        "tilhors_id": null,
        "title": 1,
           "subtotal": 0
        }
    ]
    
const result = data.map(item => {
  if(item.id === 2) {
    return item
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

If you only want to render data that matched your condition, you can have [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before calling `map` for rendering instead. And after all, you need to assign values back like below

```
liste = liste.filter((l) => l.tilhors_id === id).map((l) => <List key={l.id}>
   ...
</List>)
```

Full possible implementation

```
const listItems = (id) => {
    console.log(liste)
    if (liste === []) {
       getList()
    } else {
    liste = liste.filter((l) => l.tilhors_id === id).map((l) => <List 
                    sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 500, bgcolor: 'white' }}
                    component="nav"
                    aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
                    subheader={
                        <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
                            {l.navn}
                        </ListSubheader>
                    }
                    key={l.id}
                >
                    <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
                        <ListItemText primary={l.navn} />
                        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                    </ListItemButton>
                    {!l.subtotal ? (
                        <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                            <List component="div" disablePadding>
                                <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }} onClick={handleClick}>
                                    <div>{l.navn} {l.beloeb}</div>
                                    <ListItemText primary="Starred" />
                                    <Button>X</Button>
                                </ListItemButton>
                            </List>
                        </Collapse>) :
                        (<ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemText primary={l.navn} />
                        </ListItemButton>)}
                </List>)
 }
}
```